# python paramiko error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'"

Tags: python

I'm trying python paramiko module, got below error. How can I solve this? (I searched a lot, but no lucky)
 Any replies will be appreciated. (On Mac OS)

python2.7 aaa.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aaa.py", line 24, in <module>
    ssh_command('172.16.129.130', 22, 'user', 'password', 'ls')
  File "aaa.py", line 14, in ssh_command
    stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command(command)
  File "/Users/usera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-            packages/paramiko/client.py", line 480, in exec_command
    chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'
```

Python version

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 11:07:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Python code

```
cat aaa.py
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import paramiko

#def ssh_command(ip, port, username, password, command='pwd; ls'):
def ssh_command(ip, port, username, password, command):

    paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename.log")

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect = (ip, port, username, password)
    #stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    #input = stdin.read()
    output = stdout.read()
    #output_error = stderr.read()

    print ouput.decode('utf-8')

    # Close the connect
    client.close()

ssh_command('172.16.129.130', 22, 'user', 'password', 'ls')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is my typo.

```
client.connect = (ip, port, username, password)
```

should be

```
client.connect(ip, port, username, password)
```